# Compile maven modul during generate-sources phase

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

What I am trying to accomplish is to compile one dependent module during generate-sources phase. My module structure:

`--A 
----B`

and when I execute `mvn generate-sources` in `A` module directory I would like to build module `B`.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Since you speak about modules, do A and B have a common parent/aggregator?

Comment: Why do you want to compile another project's sources in the `generate-sources` phase?

Comment: @Tunaki because this module is only made for generating classes (which are needed for module A to proceed), and I want to generate this classes in `generate-sources` phase but I need to compile this module first.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is for project A to have a dependency on project B and make project B generate the sources in `generate-sources` phase. So when building the root POM, Maven will build B, then A and the classes will be present.

Comment: @Tunaki Sorry I might have made it unclear. In generate-sources phase I execute class from B that generates classes for module A, so B must be compiled in this phase.

Comment: If A depends on B then B will have been compiled when A is built. This does not depend on the phases involved for each project.